# SQL - PIVOT for one column and add new column

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, temp-tables, unpivot

I am fairly new to SQL. I have got this input table as

```
TypeId   EventDescription   FeedHeader     FeedHeaderValue
---------------------------------------------------------
 166         Financial       AllocRule         130
 166         Financial        DealID            0
 175       Partner Capital   InvestorID       OV_P1
 175         Investment        Querter          Q1
 175         Investment         DealID        offset
 175         Investment       InvestorID       OV_P2
```

I need an output as follows

```
 Financial    value     Partner Capital     value      Investment       value
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 AllocRule    130           InvestorID       OV_P1        Querter          Q1
 DealID        0                                          DealID           offset
                                                        InvestorID        OV_P2
```

Not sure if that is even possible. I tried using pivot but its not giving desired output

```
 select 
 [Financial] as FinancialHeader
 , [Partner Capital] as PartnerCapitalHeader
 , [Investment] as Investmentheader
  from
 (
 select  EventDescription, FeedHeader
 from [Feeder]
 ) x
 pivot
 (
   MAX(FeedHeader)
   for EventDescription in([Financial], [Partner Capital], [Investment])
  )p
```

Another approach i tried

```
Select 
    Min(Case [EventDescription] When 'Financial' Then [FeedHeader] End) 
Financial,
    Min(Case [EventDescription] When 'Financial' Then [FeedHeaderValue] End) 
 value,
     Min(Case [EventDescription] When 'Partner Capital' Then [FeedHeader] 
 End) PartnerCapital,
     Min(Case [EventDescription] When 'Partner Capital' Then 
[FeedHeaderValue] End) value,
   Min(Case [EventDescription] When 'Investment' Then [FeedHeader] End) 
 Investment,
   Min(Case [EventDescription] When 'Investment' Then [FeedHeaderValue] End) 
 value
   From [Feeder]
    Group By EventDescription
```

Is there a another way to do it?

Comment: Please tag the DBMS you're using (MySQL, PostgreSQL...)

Comment: Your result set is not clear.  Is it three rows?  Or some special column values in the last two columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was curious and did some research with `PIVOT` on SO and google and finally my luck clicked (at least what I think now)

The key point here is that you create new `EventDescription` values by appending 1 or 2 to the end depending on how many columns we want to `PIVOT`.

Without doing this, the pivot query won't work properly and would lead to error as per my experience with this task.

```
select max([Financial]) as FinancialHeader
     , max([Financial1]) as FinancialHeaderValue
     , max([Partner Capital]) as PartnerCapitalHeader
     , max([Partner Capital1]) as PartnerCapitalHeaderValue
     , max([Investment]) as InvestmentHeader
     , max([Investment1]) as InvestmentHeaderValue
from
 (select EventDescription,
         EventDescription+'1' as EventDescription1, 
         FeedHeader,
         FeedHeaderValue,
         row_number() over (partition by EventDescription order by EventDescription) rn
    from [testtable]
 ) x
 pivot
 (
   MAX(FeedHeader)
   for EventDescription in([Financial], [Partner Capital], [Investment])
 ) p
  pivot
 (
   MAX(FeedHeaderValue)
   for EventDescription1 in([Financial1], [Partner Capital1] , [Investment1] )
 ) v
group by [RN]
```

DEMO: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1d162094312e2f9588984844e2e7ee4d)

Comment: Thanks! It worked like a charm! i might try to extend this one to make it dynamic columns

Comment: Nice!! If it resolved the issue you might give it a tick by accepting the answer. Thank you.